# Scrape website for basic data using Angular JS ( facebook like Link sharing module)

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am trying to make Facebook like "Link sharing" module i.e when anyone write a link while doing new POST , it will automatically show some basic data from the website like in facebook...

I tried simple **scraping** using $http.get and it is working only if I install CORS extension in google chroome so the main issue I am facing with this approach is to make is working without using any plugin for it...

I also tried by adding headers in config file but still no luck.

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

Please share me the best approach to do this feature or if there is any way I can solve CORS issue ?

Thanks
Zeshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. CORS exists for a reason: to STOP you from accessing HTTP resources from other domains without those other domains explicitly allowing you to.

Again: ***this is not possible*** due to security restrictions imposed by browsers.

The only way you can accomplish this, and the way Facebook does it, is to move those cross-domain requests to a server, where there are no cross-domain restrictions.

So `$http.post('/some-script-on-my-server')` where that script does the actual HTTP request for the remote page, scrapes the necessary information and returns it back to the browser.

Comment: Thanks @Sergiu Paraschiv for your answer. I am just wondering how comes the google extension "CORS" make it possible with the same angular code ?

Comment: Because that extension _disables_ the CORS security restriction. You probably can't ask users of your application to install it and most of them don't even use Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this in order to have an only browser working javascript solution without configuring anything in the server (maybe useful in some particular situation) and "avoiding" CORS.

You could use the [YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/). This way you only have to play in their [console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/) a little bit with the url you need to **scrape** and use the query they provide you with in your website as url for your request.

For example (extracted from YQL website):

```
select * from html where url='http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo' and xpath='//div[@id="yfi_headlines"]/div[2]/ul/li/a'
```

Gets the headlines from yahoo finance, and you get also the query url that you can use in your request:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3Dyhoo'%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D%22yfi_headlines%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B2%5D%2Ful%2Fli%2Fa'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

They have other examples and how to integrate it in their documentation.

You don't need to configure anything in the server side, but of course, it has to go through Yahoo's, which isn't at all optimal. Of course, performance gets directly affected...

As said again, maybe in some particular situations (dev, tests, etc) this can be useful and it is always interesting to give it a try.